# Error reading JSON file using Folium geo_json

Tags: python, json, folium

I'm trying to read a JSON file from a URL using Python's Folium package but I keep getting the error- `'Map' object has no attribute 'geo_json'` or `'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`.

Here are two versions of my code using Folium-

Version 1:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import folium

def embed_map(map, path="map.html"):
    map.create_map(path=path)
    return HTML('<iframe src="files/{path}" style="width: 100%; height: 510px; 
    border: 
    none"></iframe>'.format(path=path))

geojson_url_iw='http://kodapan.se/geodata/data/2015-06-26/kommuner.geo.json'
iw_map = folium.Map(location=[60.1282,  18.6435], zoom_start=5)
iw_map.geo_json(geo_path= geojson_url_iw)
embed_map(iw_map,'iw_map.html')
```

Version 2:

```
import folium

def main():
    sweden_location  =  [ 60.1282,  18.6435 ]
    m = folium.Map(location=sweden_location, zoom_start=5)
    geojson = r'kommuner.geo.json'
    m.choropleth(geo_data=geojson)
    m.save(outfile="map.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've also tried parsing the file using json.load but it didn't work.

EDIT: Here's a snippet of the JSON file.

```
[
{
"kod": "1440",
"postnummer": "44980",
"telefon": "0303-330000",
"epost": "kommun@ale.se",
"namn": "Ale kommun",
"geometry": {
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [12.37511384238, 58.11508613311],
      [12.39092963608, 58.10816346254],
      [12.39635219392, 58.11532482191],
      [12.42572438223, 58.10768598743],
      [12.43476197863, 58.09383642732],
      [12.42120558403, 58.05488558262],
      [12.42301310331, 58.03216456268],
      [12.41081234817, 58.02474720918],
      [12.41849430511, 58.01541351467],
      [12.41578302619, 58.00703504864],
      [12.40177475177, 57.9893141188],
      [12.37421008274, 57.9936254225],
      [12.35251985138, 57.97925239172],
      [12.31004314829, 57.9658323592],
      [12.29016043621, 57.92314244749],
      [12.30462059045, 57.90586018691],
      [12.30010179225, 57.89745608439],
      [12.13712088475, 57.86669593588],
      [12.03883702389, 57.83724092156],
      [12.04335582209, 57.82436933451],
      [12.03318852614, 57.82797865449],
      [12.01488739343, 57.81414096507],
      [12.01149829477, 57.8455388528],
      [12.01043839879, 57.85719462811],
      [12.00946483558, 57.86789766962],
      [12.04403364182, 57.91617414261],
      [12.06753139246, 57.94280650831],
      [12.08741410454, 57.95491649705],
      [12.12107915114, 57.97109673256],
      [12.13056862736, 58.01013890686],
      [12.13452604959, 58.01383335415],
      [12.16360303253, 58.00790882552],
      [12.1706326328, 58.01654138344],
      [12.22079841655, 58.02280291623],
      [12.23166234424, 58.02534106327],
      [12.24284579922, 58.0331235912],
      [12.23613572623, 58.03853652482],
      [12.24220674465, 58.04259568725],
      [12.27895238243, 58.06136331836],
      [12.33550871188, 58.08383768027],
      [12.35020696699, 58.10697317331],
      [12.37511384238, 58.11508613311]
    ]
  ],
  "type": "Polygon"
},
"url": "http://www.ale.se/",
"postort": "ALAFORS"
},
```

And here's the URL- http://kodapan.se/geodata/data/2015-06-26/kommuner.geo.json

Answer (score 0):

unless you need to use folium directly I would recommend loading the pre-installed json package:

```
import json

data = your_file.json()
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

If your Json is stored as a string you can do this:

```
data = json.loads(your_file)
```

EDIT 2:

Thanks for providing the string.

The problem seems to be that the string has square parantheses around it. You can evaluate the string which would make it a list and then grab the first (and only) item. This file would be a dictionary which would presumably serve your purpose. You should be able to solve the problem like this:

```
new_dict = eval(your_file)[0]
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm getting an error: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'.

Comment: I've tried that before, didn't work too. :(
Error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: could you maybe add the string to your question? That might help

Comment: I've added the link to the file and also a snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182104/discussion-between-dustbunny-and-dominique-paul).